# Opening Xcode help file and application at the same time

Tags: iphone, xcode, ide

I am noobs at Xcode. I am on my second day of learning.

When I start Xcode, the main window has a button for "Getting Started with Xcode" and a subsequent link for "Xcode workflow tutorial"

Now I would simply like the help to be open at the same time as the IDE so that I can read and code. I clicked on the Xcode icon that opened up the original instance, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

How do I get both things to stay open at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps -

Step 1: On opening X-Code, this window turns up-[image]

Step 2: On clicking **Getting started with Xcode** , gives -[image]

Step 3: On clicking **Start Developing with Xcode** gives-[image]

Step 4: On clicking the link - **Xcode Workflow tutorial** present in `Write a Sample Application` gives-[image]

**Notice that in all the process your Xcode menubar remains unchanged** i.e.,[image]

Now, Click on `File`(or `Cmd + Shift + N` keyboard shortcut) , and select `New Project` should pop up the windows as shown in Workflow tutorial. Select the application type, saving should bring you new Xcode project. Arranging the two windows side by side should look some what like this -[image]

**Now code while you learn from the Workflow tutorial :)**

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the documentation window via Cmd-Option-? and search for Getting Started with Xcode there.  The option to open the documentation is also under the Help menu.

I generally open a project first and then open the documentation afterwards, if necessary.

Comment: I hit the Cmd-Option-? combination, but nothing happened.

Comment: Are you sure Xcode is in the foreground? Try going to Help > Developer Documentation.