# switching between help and code window

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just found out how to have help open and the code editor open at the same time from an answer to this question: [Opening Xcode help file and application at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675680/opening-xcode-help-file-and-application-at-the-same-time/4675872#4675872)

In Windows, Alt+Tab switched me back and forth to my hearts content. Here, Alt tab bring up the next open application (happens to be Firefox in my case).

How do I switch between the Xcode window and the help window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> will switch back and forth between windows within a Mac application.

You can also use <kbd>F10</kbd> to see all of the application's windows in a zoomed out view and pick one to focus with the mouse or keyboard.